# GNU Parallel - Usar arquivo com dados de variáveis dentro de um script

Tags: script, bash, paralelismo

Gostaria de uma ajuda com o GNU Parallel.

É possível ler variáveis de um arquivo e passar estas variáveis para dentro de um script bash via Parallel?
Por exemplo:
Tenho um arquivo chamado `dados.txt` contendo:

```
maça vermelha
banana amarela
uva verde
```

E um script `lista.sh` que precisa ler cada uma destas linhas como sendo 2 variáveis: `$fruta` e `$cor`

O script seria algo assim:

```
echo Fruta: $fruta
echo Cor: $cor
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Com a opção `--colsep` da pra usar as colunas do arquivo como delimitador.

**dados.txt**

```
maça vermelha
banana amarela
uva verde
```

**lista.sh**

```
echo Fruta $1
echo Cor $2
```

**comando**

```
parallel --colsep ' ' ./lista.sh :::: dados.txt
```

**resultado**

```
Fruta maça
Cor vermelha
Fruta banana
Cor amarela
Fruta uva
Cor verde
```